# UITextField Clear Button Does Not Show

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I want to show a clear button always in a UITextField. I have tried to both set this in .xib Interface Builder:
[image]
and in code using this line: `[_firstNameField setClearButtonMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];`

Neither causes the button to show. Help please.

Comment: Just as a side comment. It's UITextField that has the "clearButtonMode" property, not UITextView as you have it in your question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you set it to `UITextFieldViewModeAlways` the clear button appears as long as there is text on the UITextField.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ahh. That makes sense. It's sort of depressing to know that I wasted an hour on that though. :(

Comment: Sorry. It wouldn't allow me for a while so I decided to come back.