# Clear button of UITextField does not appear in iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, ios9, xcode7

The clear button of UITextField gets hidden in iOS 9, it was working perfectly till now in all other iOS versions. I tried out everything from the below links :

(1). [UITextField Clear Button Does Not Show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369473/uitextfield-clear-button-does-not-show)
(2). [How to change the tint color of the clear button on a UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27944781/how-to-change-the-tint-color-of-the-clear-button-on-a-uitextfield)
(3). [UITextField clearButtonMode color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274210/uitextfield-clearbuttonmode-color)

The button does not show up till we hover the mouse over its position.
In storyboard, I have selected "appears while editing" option and even tried "is always visible" option, but still the same.

I don't want to create custom button, so please let me know is there anything wrong in iOS 9 or what else can be done to resolve.

Waiting for a positive reply.

Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

Check the property for the specific button, textfield where you have declared, whether you had mentioned property as "Weak". If at all you have mentioned as weak please change it to "Strong".